# Приложение или уточняющий оборот?

Tags: приложение, уточнения

Чем представлены ниженаписанные обороты: приложениями или уточняющими? Также как следует расставлять запятые при тире - поглощает ли тире запятую или нет и когда?

> Чем яснее было небо, тем яснее становилось сознание Александра — того самого защитника, что поклялся защищать свою родину и не предавать ее.
>
> Приблизившись к землям вождества, лорд — Харрингтон Железное Сердце, некогда бывший в регулярной армии эрла, — кинул клич пламени войны.
>
> Трэлл, а именно Асмунд, не видел и малейшего шанса на побег.